¿Alguien me puede identificar el uso de "éste" en esta frase?
Tengo una duda relacionada con este extracto de la Ilíada de Homero

Después de una corta invocación a la divinidad para que cante "la
perniciosa ira de Aquiles", nos refiere el poeta que Crises, sacerdote
de Apolo, va al campamento aqueo para rescatar a su hija, que había
sido hecha cautiva y adjudicada como esclava a Agamenón; éste
desprecia al sacerdote, se niega a darle la hija y lo despide con
amenazadoras palabras; Apolo, indignado, suscita una terrible peste en
el campamento

¿A quién se refiere el pronombre "éste" señalado en negrita?
Aún más, ¿quién es el sujeto del verbo despreciar? Creo que es el sacerdote pero se usa el "personal a" así que me pone confundido.

"Este" (o "Éste") se refiere al último sustantivo masculino, Agamenón. Es Agamenón quien desprecia al sacerdote (decimos "al sacerdote" porque es un objeto directo personal: desprecia la religión / desprecia AL sacerdote)

Just to expand on @Gustavson's comment it is useful to remember that these demonstrative pronouns are used in Spanish to refer back in a way which we do in English with former and latter. So este refers to the nearest previously mentioned noun (hence in English the latter) and aquel to the furthest away noun (in English the former). In the example quoted only one is used and refers to Agamemnon. Crises (Chryses) is probably too far away for the use of aquel which would anyway be ambiguous as aquel might refer to the god Apolo (Apollo).

Good point. Notice, however, that Crises is Apolo's priest, so "aquél" could only have worked there if there had been a subject/object inversion: aquél (Crises) es despreciado por Agamenón.

Yo llegué a éste sitio casi por accidente pero no es porque me gusta hacerle perder el perder el tiempo. Pero algo hay que decir y comunicar al mismo tiempo. Chao y saludos.

Lo peor de todo es que en tu respuesta está mal puesta la tilde en éste
